# Amazon Image Creation from m3.medium to r3.large

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created AMI image on AWS and the instance type is m3.medium.My question is We planned to upgrade the instance from m3.medium to R3*XLarge i'm unable to select the image for this type and it was disable by default.Any Clues ?

Comment: Are you resizing the existing instance or launching a new instance from the base AMI? Since they are both R3 VMs, they should have no problem running a 64 bit HVM image. Was the image created from the R3 large, or off of another type of VM?

Comment: Yes, sorry I edited my question.I'm looking to upgrade from m3.medium to R3*large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [Amazon Linux AMI Instance Type Matrix](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/), you will see which AMIs are supported by different instance types.

You will see that M3s support HVM and PV, but R3s only support HVM. If you cannot select your AMI for an R3 this means your original AMI must be a PV and cannot be used.

Unfortunately there is no way around this that I know of. The only solution is to use an HVM AMI if you want to run it on an R3. Your best alternative for power is a C3 which supports PV but doesn't have as much RAM.

Comment: Neatly explained.Thanks.

Comment: great explanation. +1

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to reinstall your environment in the R3 instance (you can use Rsync or move the M3 contents as a .tar file) and then point your elastic IP to it without terminating the M3 instance (just in case you have to rollback).

This is the hard way but the billing savings are massive if you depend on ram.